# Voltage-drop resistor to power a 19 V computer

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator, computers

I am considering using a voltage-drop resistor to drop the 21.6 V ± 1% on a power supply down to 19 V.

If this was an LED, I would use a 1 Ω, 7 W resistor but this seems to be a very big size.

In this case I have 4 Chromebox that ask for 19 V and 3.42 A. Is there a better way this can be done other than with a resistor?

If a resistor is the best option, what tolerance is likely safe?

Comment: Is this specifically a 21.6V power supply? Some supplies will output slightly higher voltages when unloaded. Also fwiw I can jam 20V into my 19V laptop without letting the smoke  out.

Comment: @Bryan generally I would do the same and stuff 20V into just one but this is multiple units, what I'm thinking of using is a meanwell PSU and  easy to get a hold of at around $40 is adjustable from 21.6V up to 24V @ 350W

Comment: That’s a great deal on the power supply , but it will cost you in the post regulation. Assuming that those chrome books really will use that much current and you use an LDO to drop the 2.6 volts you’ll be wasting 9 watts per unit, almost 36W.

Comment: You might be able to find a high power white LED (possibly a module) that drops about 2.5V at 3.5A. It'll just be a hella bright power on light that can also be a room light or reading light, or (if UV) a germicidal accessory or tanning attachment. If nothing else, use it for a hand, foot, or fanny warmer... ;)

Comment: Aside - 19V and 19.5V PSUs are quite common amongst laptops, both in HP and Thinkpad and probably many others.   It may be an option to find some used PSUs - try a computer recycling org, they often have boxes of PSUs from laptops that have failed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The LED is a constant current load, more or less. Not so your Chromeboxen, which can vary their currents widely. So a dropping resistor will not work. At low load the voltage will be too high, possibly damaging your computer boards.

In this case it’s probably better just to find a 19V supply. Fortunately that’s a common one for laptops. Amazon turns up a lot of them.

Comment: `The LED is a constant current load, more or less`? An LED exhibits diode V/I relation: on the other side of resistive/proportional, sometimes being used like a Zener diode/voltage reference. (Or to "drop voltage", as [PStechPaul suggests](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649542/voltage-drop-resistor-to-power-a-19v-computer#comment1724839_649542).)

Comment: Or if you like living on the edge, you could just plug in the 21.6V supply. It might work fine. Or it might break the Chromebook. Or it might work fine but stress the computer's power supply more so that it wears out faster and breaks sooner. I really do think a computer power supply (inside the computer) designed for 19V can probably handle 21.6V, but it's entirely at your own risk.

Comment: @greybeard for a given voltage the LED + load resistor will be a constant current.

Answer (score 13):

What about serial connectivity of 3 or 4 rectifier diodes (anode to + of power supply)?
Each diode have forward bias voltage drop of around 0.6V - 0.7V.

Comment: better option than a resistor for sure

Comment: A high-current bridge rectifier package would be ideal since it has good heat dissipation, a higher Vf (which tends to scale with max current), and you can easily choose between 1 (~to+/-) or 2 junction drops (+to-).

Comment: with about 10W to be dissipated (see the V drop and Imax requested by OP), as a byproduct you also get a very nice tea heater, which can alternatively be used to light your cigarettes or heat hands when the zombie apocalypse comes. /s

Answer (score 5):

**Just plug it in directly.**

Seriously, your 21.6 V is just about 10% away from the rated 19 V input. Taking into account whatever tolerance that 19 V is supposed to have, you're just a few percent above the rated maximum input voltage.

Nothing in a computer runs directly off of the 19 V input. It's all fed through various DC-DC converters to drop it down to the battery voltage and to the 12V/5V/3.3V/1.xV voltages expected by the different components.

No sane manufacturer is going to design a board for 19 V using parts that fail under 21 V. You're not going to put 20 V caps or semiconductors into a circuit meant to run really close to that voltage level all the time, that would be madness.

So most likely, everything will run just fine from 21.6 V. If the board is a bit too picky, there is a chance it will signal an error of some sort and refuse to work on that voltage (shut itself off). There's really no chance anything could burn up (as long as you get the polarity right!), so just give it a try and see.

Comment: I wanted to answer this but not take responsibility if it does break :)

Comment: @user253751 I think that if we take the already very small probability that it does break and multiply it by the probability of OP managing to find out where I live, the result is a risk which I'm willing to take :)

Comment: I wonder why power supplies and devices that use them aren't often labeled with any indication of tolerance?  Some devices that are marked "5V" need between 4.75 and 5.25 volts, while others would be equallyhappy with anything between 3.6 and 9 volts, but there's no way to tell which devices will tolerate what.

Comment: @supercat That would be fantastic. 5V is extra problematic because there's case where the 5V is going directly into sensitive 5V components (µc, opamps, etc.) vs into internal regulator which turns it into 3.3V or even lower. Here we can make some inference about potential tolerances, because as TooTea said, nothing in common computer type electronics uses 19V directly. So if there is a problem, it's because of extra heat dissipation in internal regulators.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the resistor approach is one of the worst ideas. The consumed current will vary between e.g. 0.3A and 3.2A and you will get both heat and voltage variaton up to 21.3V (assuming your 21.6V source is itself stable).

The proper way is to use a switching mode (buck-type) regulator, assuming that your source never actually goes below 19V + the regulator minimum dropout.

On the other hand, one should always check not only the required parameters (e.g. voltage), but their allowed tolerances as well. It is quite possible that you can simply plug the chromebox directly into 21.6V source and if this is the case you will save energy, effort, complexity and money at once.

Few different dc-powered motherboards that I have dealt with came with 19V supplies but in fact were good from 10V all the way to 28V.

On the other hand, few another ones required much tighter power spec, e.g. 12V ± 5% and actually did fail outside this range.

YMMV.

There is at least one chromebox model that works equally well at 12V and 20V for prolonged periods. We discovered this fact out of negligence.

Answer (score 0):

An LED is one of the only devices this approach works with.  It's imperfect but an LED can be treated like it has a fixed junction voltage it *will* drop no matter the current provided.  As such you can calculate the resistor to drop the rest of the voltage at the current you desire.

A computer is not going to behave that way and will probably accept whatever input voltage you give it until it breaks.  It's power draw will vary over time acting like an ever changing resistor value causing the voltage to fluctuate up and down.

A linear regulator might be the most appropriate component for the kind of voltage-reduction by brute force and power-dissipation you intended.

If you still want to use only resistors you could (in theory) build a (massively oversized) voltage divider out of two power resistors and place the laptop in parallel to one of them. Think something like 216ohm and 1900ohm with the laptop in parallel to the 1900ohm (if such perfect resistor values exist).  This would get you the correct voltage if requiring scaling of the resistors for available current.  But it would waste the vast majority of your power as heat.  Even this would fail for a high-drain device like a laptop (but works pretty well for very low-drain parts on a board) as the resistor and laptop in parallel would effectively have a lower resistance than the original divider resistor.  And you wouldn't even be able to compensate because the effective 'resistance' of the laptop as drain varied would still fluctuate so the voltage would remain unstable.

Also it might catch fire.

As long as you want a stable DC voltage from a DC source I think you will need some sort of chip or a very complicated circuit design.

Comment: A voltage divider would need to burn off more energy than the laptop if it were to maintain at least 50% of nominal voltage.  That's not a sensible suggestion to make.

Comment: Oh absolutely, I know that and I work in software.  I just think learning to think like that is useful even to the discussion.